# Set processorThreadMax per site in IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

Is there a way to set the processorThreadMax configration in IIS7.5 at a per website level?  I can set the value for all of IIS, but when I look at the value in the website's ASP.NET settings, it's grayed out.

Comment: That setting only affects Classic ASP behaviour and not ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there anything that limits threads in ASP.NET?

Comment: You might want to look at the `<processModel>` config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  However it's a machine-wide config section. What is the problem that you're having?